# Flatten JSON into array of strings while appending

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON objet that I am trying to convert.  I need to flatten the list while also appending all sub-values to the list as well.

this is what I am starting with.

```
 "message": {
      "arctic":[],
      "atlantic":[
             "north",
             "south",
      ],
      "indian":[],
      "pacific":[
             "north",
             "south",
      ],
      "southern":[],
}
```

and I need it to be an array of strings with both the origin and submodules in the list.  It needs to be in this format:

```
"message": [
 "artic",
 "atlantic",
 "north atlantic",
 "south atlantic",
 "indian",
 "pacific",
 "north pacific",
 "south pacific",
 "southern"
]
```

I have tried many things but nothing seems to work properly.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: This question isn't really related to JSON, so much as to transforming a JavaScript object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could flat map the entries of the object.

```js
function flat(object) {
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => [k, ...v.map(s => `${s} ${k}`)]);
}

var data = { message: { arctic: [], atlantic: ["north", "south"], indian: [], pacific: ["north", "south"], southern: [] } },
    result = { message: flat(data.message) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was me i'd use a for in loop and for each record join the key and the strings in the array.

So it would be something like the following (haven't tested this):

```
let output = [];

for(key in json) {
    if(!!json[key].length) output.push(key);
    else                   json[key].forEach(elem => { output.push(`${elem} ${key})` }); 
}
```

`
Hope this helps! good luck!

EDIT: Nina's solution looks cleaner though :p

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, what I posted was incorrect, didn't notice that keys must be combined with array items. Besides, if we have one-level arrays, everything is much simpler:

```
function flat(item) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push(key);
            var sublist = item[key];
            for (var i = 0; i < sublist.length; i++) {
                result.push(sublist[i] + ' ' + key);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var result = flat(obj);
```

Sorry About that